# changing button based on bootstrap collapse state

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I am using bootstrap.

I have the HTML code below:

```
 <div class="row">
        <button id="dog-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dog-section" onclick="petToggle()">Show Pet</button>
    </div>


    <div class="col-12 collapse" id="dog-section">
```

I have the JS below:

```
function petToggle() {
          var dogDiv = document.getElementById("dog-section");
          var dogBtn = document.getElementById("dog-btn");
 
        }
```

In my website the starting state of dog-section is variable. Sometimes it could be visible sometimes it can be closed. I tried using :hidden and :visible with jquery to get the initial state of the div but it didn't work as it always returned true or always returned false. My desired outcome: if dog-section is hidden because of Bootstrap dropdown I want the button to read Show Pet. If the dog-section is visible, I want it to read Hide Pet.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional to check if the css is set to **visible** if it is then set it to **hidden**.

### With jQuery:

To check:

```
if(dogSection.css('visibility') === 'hidden'){
  // make it visible
}else{
  // hide it
}
```

To set visible:

```
dogSection.css('visibility', 'visible')
```

To set hidden:

```
dogSection.css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

```js
const $btn = $('#dog-btn')
const $dogSection = $('#dog-section')

function petToggle(){
  $btn.click(function(){
    if($dogSection.css('visibility') === 'hidden'){
      $dogSection.css('visibility', 'visible')
      $btn.text("Hide Pet Section")
    }else{
      $dogSection.css('visibility', 'hidden')
      $btn.text("Show Pet Section")
    }
  })
}

petToggle()
```

```css
#dog-section {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <button id="dog-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dog-section">Show Pet Section</button>
</div>


<div class="col-12 collapse" id="dog-section">
   <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/sleeping-dogs-curled-up.jpg" alt="Sleeping Dog" width="450" height="355"> 
  <img href="">
</div>
```

### Using vanilla Javascript...

Depending on how you are displaying your `#dog-section` in the DOM you can use one of the following.

```
if(getComputedStyle(dogSection).getPropertyValue('visibility') === 'hidden')
```

```
if(getComputedStyle(dogSection).getPropertyValue('display') === 'none')
```

```
if(dogSection.style.visibility === 'hidden';
```

```
if(dogSection.style.display === 'none';
```

Then set it using one of the following:

```
dogSection.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible')
```

```
dogSection.style.visibility = 'visible'
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('dog-btn')
const dogSection = document.getElementById('dog-section')

function petToggle(){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(getComputedStyle(dogSection).getPropertyValue('visibility') === 'hidden'){
      dogSection.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible')
      btn.textContent = "Hide Pet Section"
    }else{
      dogSection.style.setProperty('visibility', 'hidden')
      btn.textContent = "Show Pet Section"
    }
  })
}

petToggle()
```

```css
#dog-section {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <button id="dog-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dog-section">Show Pet Section</button>
</div>


<div class="col-12 collapse" id="dog-section">
   <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/sleeping-dogs-curled-up.jpg" alt="Sleeping Dog" width="450" height="355"> 
  <img href="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `petToggle` function. You need to use the collapse events to achieve what you want. Here's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events).

Since dog-section might be hidden or shown initially, you can check the display style of the section and change button text accordingly.

```js
// check the initial display state of the dog-section
// if it's hidden, set the button text to "Show Pet"
// if it's shown, set the button text to "Hide Pet"
if ($("#dog-section").css("display") === "none") {
    $("#dog-btn").text("Show Pet");
} else {
    $("#dog-btn").text("Hide Pet");
}

// set the button text to "Hide Pet" when dog-section is shown
$("#dog-section").on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
    $("#dog-btn").text("Hide Pet");
});

// set the button text to "Show Pet" when dog-section is hidden
$("#dog-section").on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
    $("#dog-btn").text("Show Pet");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button id="dog-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dog-section">Show Pet</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 collapse" id="dog-section">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam quia suscipit amet ex aut. Odit error dolorem tempore, officiis sed, fugit in voluptate laboriosam quas illo ipsa alias magnam! Odit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```